# Write this Visual Basic code in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

How to write the following VB code in PB?

```vb
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject()

For Each str As Scripting.Drive In fso.Drives
    If str.IsReady Then
       TextBox1.Text += "Volume Name : " & str.VolumeName 
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
OLEObject ole_wsh
string ls_values, ls_message

 ole_wsh = CREATE OLEObject
 ole_wsh.ConnectToNewObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
 ole_wsh.Language = "vbscript"
 ole_wsh.AddCode('Function retDrives()~r~n' &
 + 'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")~r~n' &
 + 'drivesVolume = ""~r~n' &
 + 'For Each str In fso.Drives ~r~n' &
 + '   If str.IsReady Then ~r~n' &
 + '      drivesVolume = drivesVolume + "[" + str.VolumeName + "]" ~r~n' &
 + '   End If ~r~n' &
 + 'Next~r~n' &
 + 'retDrives=drivesVolume~r~n' &
 + 'End Function')


 ls_values = ole_wsh.Eval("retDrives")
 ole_wsh.DisconnectObject()
 DESTROY ole_wsh

ls_message = "VOLUMES(s): " + ls_values
MessageBox("DRIVES",ls_message)
```

Comment: If you can create `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl`, why not create `Scripting.FileSystemObject` directly?

Comment: @GSerg, Well ... that's not what the OP asked  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to declare and use a Windows API for this type of functionality.  Probably GetLogicalDrives or similar.  You may wish to take a look at the Filesys application by Roland Smith of Topwiz Software (www.topwizprogramming.com under Free Code).  This sample application has many system information / manipulation methods coded.

Comment: So did the downvote individual actually try anything or are they just unhappy with having to figure something out themselves?